`pzstd` = parallelized Zstandard, how to watch progress in 4TB large file/disk?
I am brand new to zstd/pzstd, trying out its features, compression, benchmarking it, and so on. (I run Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon.) This computer has 32 GB RAM.
The basic command appears to be working, but I found out it's not fully multi-threaded / parallelized:
# zstd --ultra --adapt=min=5,max=22 --long --auto-threads=logical --progress --keep --force --verbose /dev/nvme0n1 -o /absolute/path/to/file/on/external/disk.zst

As you can see for yourself, I am trying to compress my NVMe 4TB drive with only Timeshifts on its ext4 fs. Could you recommend me some tweaks to my zstd command, I would welcome it.
But the real question here is how to make it multi-threaded / parallelized?

I am trying this:
# pzstd --ultra -22 --processes 8 --keep --force --verbose /dev/nvme0n1 -o /absolute/path/to/file/on/external/disk.zst

because of this parallel version of ZSTD does not have apparently the --progress option. I need to find another way to watch it. 4TB will take some time and I don't intend to be totally blind.
My tries with pv ended as not working properly. Please help, I'll appreciate it. Thanks.

It was not obvious to me, that I need to remove --verbose option sadly. Better late than never, right...

# pv </dev/nvme0n1 | pzstd -10 --processes 8 >/path/to/file/on/external/disk.zst

It is a speedy solution for my lower end CPU i7-7700hq. If you have a very fast one, you might test higher compression than -10 up to an --ultra -22.
Cheers

Information sources:

Ubuntu man page on pzstd
Ubuntu man page on zstd
Wikipedia on Zstandard
Official GitHub Facebook page

